# Array get the label that refers to the highest value

Tags: javascript

I have the following within an ajax success:

```
          var arrayRating = [];
          var arrayRating2 = [];
            var hnumb = 0;
            var highestProp; 
            for (var key in json.rating) {
                if ( json.rating[key] > hnumb )
                {
                   hnumb = json.rating[key]/10;
                   highestProp = key;
                }

              arrayRating.push(hnumb);

            }

          var higestNumb = Math.max.apply(null, arrayRating);
```

where higestNumb  gives me the highest number from "arrayRating".

I would like to access the property that matches the highest number in the case below I would like to have "location" stored in a variable.

I have tried as follow:

```
          arrayRating2.push(json.rating);
```

console.log(arrayRating2) return the follow:

```
[Object]
    0: Object
        atmosphere: 72
        cleanliness: 75
        facilities: 69
        location: 94
        overall: 79
        security: 84
        staff: 83
        valueForMoney: 77
```

Comment: highestProp is what u want.

Answer (score 0):

This works ;)

```
var obj = {
  a: 2,
  b: 3,
  c: 7,
  d: 1,
  e: 12,
  f: -4,
  g: -2
}

function findHighestProp(obj) {
  var highest = 0;
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    var prop = obj[key];
    if (prop > highest) highest = prop;
  });
  return highest;
}

console.log(findHighestProp(obj)); // 12
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Tomasito665/fLwjz4d2/)